# How to sort a list of int list

Tags: c#, sorting, generics, integer

Please let me know how can I sort a List which contains lists of integers.

```
List<List<int>> numberLists = new List<List<int>>();
numberLists.Add(new List<int>() { 6, 8, 9 });
numberLists.Add(new List<int>() { 2, 4, 7 });
numberLists.Add(new List<int>() { 4, 7, 8 });
numberLists.Add(new List<int>() { 2, 3, 9 });
```

How to sort the above List to have following result?

```
 2, 3, 9
 2, 4, 7
 4, 7, 8
 6, 8, 9
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can write compare function fo compare list as elements

Comment: What is your criteria? Why is 2,3,9 < 2,4,7? Why is 4,7,8 > 2,4,7?

Comment: It is a little bit unclear what you are asking because every child list inside your parent list is already sorted. So you could get your desired result by sorting the list by the first number in every list : `var result = numberLists.OrderBy(x => x[0]).ToList();`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry, I was not specific enough.

The challenge was to sort the list by based on its elements:
first by [0]th then by [1]th and finally by [2]th element

In the meanwhile TheGeneral already provided the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
var results = numberLists.OrderBy(x => x[0])
                         .ThenBy(x => x[1])
                         .ThenBy(x => x[2]);

foreach (var result in results)
{
   foreach (var subresult in result)
   {
      Console.Write(subresult + " ");
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output**

```
2 3 9
2 4 7
4 7 8
6 8 9
```

---

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FmqjEp)

---

**Additional Results**

[Enumerable.OrderBy Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a
>   key.

[Enumerable.ThenBy Method (IOrderedEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in
>   ascending order according to a key.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works and this is exactly what I was looking for. ;)

Comment: @JánosZoltánKis if this has solved your problem don't forget to up vote and mark as correct

Comment: I already voted, but unfortunately I have not yet reached 15 reputations, therefore my feedbacks are not visible.
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JánosZoltánKis Ahh ok, then also make sure you press the tick, this will give you 2 reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple way base on your criteria

```
var sortedLists = numberLists.OrderBy(x => string.Join(",", x.ToArray())).ToList();
```

just convert it to string then compare as string